# Question about phrasal verbs

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

My student yesterday said **"I asked around the people for directions."** but I corrected it to **"I asked THE PEOPLE around me for directions."**(I changed the order). I couldn't provide a good explanation for why I did that. Can someone please help me do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The term *ask around* is a phrasal verb that functions intransitively:

> I **asked around** for directions. Finally, I found someone who could assist me.

The verb *ask* by itself can act transitively, where you specify who you are asking:

> I **asked** three strangers for directions. Finally, I found someone who could assist me.

Interestingly enough, the dictionary on my Mac says:

> • [ *no obj*. ] (**ask around**) talk to various people in order to find something out: *there are fine meals to be had if you ask around*.

The way your version reads could be parsed like this:

> "I **asked** [the people around me] [for directions]."

Answer (score 0):

To me, it should be corrected as :  *I asked the people around for directions* since the verb *ask* is transitive, and  by putting *around* before *the people*, the object will be missed because *around* in the first is a preposition not adverb.

Comment: You do offer a grammatical sentence using transitive **ask**, but the verb "ask around" means "to inquire", and is intransitive.